# Sentry: Event has no Stack trace

Tags: android, logging, stack-trace, sentry

We are using Sentry for error logging.
This works fine for real exceptions and crashes but when sending **Events** I need a Stack trace, too.
However, these Events have no StackTrace in the Sentry website.

I have set the config options to

```
  options.isAttachStacktrace = true
  options.isAttachThreads = true
```

And my message for sending warnings looks like this

```
fun logWarning(warning: Exception) {
    val event = SentryEvent()
    event.level = SentryLevel.WARNING
    event.message = Message()
    event.message.message = warning.message
    Sentry.captureEvent(event)
}
```

Gradle is set to:

Project:

```
classpath 'io.sentry:sentry-android-gradle-plugin:1.7.35'
```

App:

```
apply plugin: 'io.sentry.android.gradle'

apply pluginsentry {
    autoProguardConfig true
    autoUpload true
    uploadNativeSymbols false
    includeNativeSources false
}: 'io.sentry.android.gradle'

implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android-core:2.3.1'
implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-core:2.3.1'
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `isAttachThreads = true`, this should work. What version of the SDK is this? Could you create a small reproduction app so we can debug this, please?

Comment: But do I have to add something for the logWarning method maybe? This attachThreads is only from the Config.
In Gradle I use

implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android-core:2.3.1'
implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-core:2.3.1'

Comment: I noticed that SentryEvent has the property of Fingerprint. Is this perhaps usefull in my case?

Comment: If you configure with `attachStacktrace`, all events include a stacktrace, even just messages without an exception. If that's not the case this is likely a bug. Can you please try the latest alpha 3.0.0-alpha.3? Or please share a small app that reproduces the issue so we can investigate. Feel free to raise an issue here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I'm not using sentry-java but instead sentry-android-core and sentry-core. (Sorry, it gets a bit confusing). But is it possible to use sentry-java for Android, too?

Comment: Speifically I used the sample gradle config from github. There one is supposed to use   implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:2.1.3' so what's the right way to do this via sentry-java?

Comment: You're doing the right thing. That repository holds the Java and Android SDK, you can raise the issue there. Ideally with a small sample repro we can investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a bug https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-android/pull/540
it should be fixed by 3.0.0-alpha.3, we are making a new release on Monday btw

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But somehow the version 3 is causing other issues, giving me an error back "CSRF Verification Failed" Did something else change there?

Comment: this looks like a server error, nothing really changed about that, do you have on-premise Sentry or sentry.io?

Comment: Hey there, no it is self hosted. But I haven't had that issue in version 2.